# Google Fonts Look Weird on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, wordpress, fonts

So I imported multiple google fonts to my Wordpress site, vhawley.com, and when I pull them up on the computer they show up fine, but when I pull them up on my iPhone, (maybe other mobile devices, thats just all I have as far as phones) it looks like its almost being layer on on top of the other! I just don't get it! My link is fine, I've tried multiple fonts, but nothing works. Is this a common problem that can just be fixed easily?

[vhawley.com](http://www.vhawley.com)

If you go to the site, I just got done with it, it's my sisters, how do you like it? The colors won't always be like that keep in mind.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: I basically said that I have no idea what could be wrong. How much more info do you guys want? Give specifics of what to say so that I can please everyone in the future.

Comment: 1) Don't link to an external site. Once you fix it, it will no longer be useful as an example to what is wrong. 2) Include the problem code here in your post. For this question that would include the CSS and HTML markup that looks wrong when rendered. See here for more information on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thats the thing, the code is fine, its just that for some reason it is showing up fine on my computer, and the font itself looks weird on my phone, if there was a problem with the code, it would either look weird on the computer too, or it just wouldn't show up at all on my phone and/or computer.

Comment: That's not necessarily correct. Mobile browsers render code differently than desktop browsers. There may be something in your CSS that is missing that is mobile specific.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Honestly I just checked it out from a few different browsers, that font doesn't look good at all. Why don't you try a different font and see if you still have the same problem?

Comment: Thank you, however I have tried many different ones, and they still don't seem to work. Have any easy suggestions for a thin, good looking font?

Comment: I would use Helvetica, very clean font right out of the box. Try it out I'm sure you will like it! Also, you can set the font-weight property to make it as thin as you like.

try the following:

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:helvetica;font-weight:100;}

Don't forget to remove the google font first!

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I'll give that one a try, I mean, I never really liked/trusted google anyway.

Comment: LOL, I like them, but I can't say i trust them either... I would like to know what you think of it though, post back with results

Answer (score -2):

I would use Helvetica, very clean font right out of the box. Try it out I'm sure you will like it! Also, you can set the font-weight property to make it as thin as you like. try the following:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:helvetica;font-weight:100;}
```

Don't forget to remove the google font first!